# setting button background color bug?

Tags: android, button, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-button, android-jetpack-compose-button

I've tried to set the background color of buttons with custom hex values:

colors.xml:

```
    <color name="red">#F67070</color>
    <color name="blue">#00B2FF</color>
```

```
Button(
    onClick = {}
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
        backgroundColor = Color(R.color.red)
    )
)
{
    Text(text = "Cancel")
}
```

but that results in:

[image]

and (as you can guess) isn't either the color nor the way I would like it to look like
I've found other way to change the background color ("backgroundColor = Color(0xFFF67070)")

[image]

but this bit of code looks confusing, how can I change the background color of that button using resources?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's not very clear.

Comment: I'm trying to set the background color of button to value saved in colors.xml, that's all

Comment: Try `colorResource()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the method [**`colorResource`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/res/package-summary#colorResource(kotlin.Int))

```
Button(
    onClick = {},
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.red)
    )
){
    Text(text = "Cancel")
}
```

[image]